# Android - Where to put removeUpdates for Location Manager

Tags: java, android, locationlistener

I have following code (I know that some of that may be redundant, if yes, please let me know). What I can't do is to stop the invoking updating the location again and again. I tried some different ways where to stop it (they are present in the code but commented). Sometimes i get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jangcy.emergency/jangcy.emergency.ReportStartActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null
```

and sometimes

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference
```

If I try to stop it with some int (like is done now), it doesn't really stop. If I remove the if, it stops before it sends location to DB.

Any help please?

```
package jangcy.emergency;

import android.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReportStartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String user;
TextView textView;
private double latitude = 500;
private double longitude = 500;
double old_longitude = 499;
double old_latitude = 499;


LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
private int idZgloszenia;
public int counter = 0;

private static final String url_start_report = "http://192.168.0.12:80/emergency/start_report.php";


private StringRequest request;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_start);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
    textView.setText("jangcy");

    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user = sharedPref.getString("loginKey", null);

    int ik = geoLocation();
    if (ik == 5){

        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        locationManager = null;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET

            }, 10);
            return;
        }

    } else {
        //configureButton();
    }

}

public int geoLocation()
{
    final int[] do_zwrotu = new int[1];
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude) + " " + String.valueOf(latitude));

            if (longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180 && latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90) {

                do_zwrotu[0] = 5;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude) + " " + String.valueOf(latitude) + user);
                startReport(user, longitude, latitude);

                /*locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                locationManager = null;*/

                /*locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                locationManager = null;*/


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent in = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
return do_zwrotu[0];
}


private void startReport(final String user, final double longitude, final double latitude) {

    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_start_report, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                System.out.println(response);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);



                int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1) {

                    /*
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    locationManager = null;*/

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //idZgloszenia = jsonObject.getInt("id_zgloszenia");
                    //textView.setText(idZgloszenia);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            hashMap.put("gps_x", Double.toString(longitude));
            hashMap.put("gps_y", Double.toString(latitude));
            hashMap.put("uzytkownik", user);
            return hashMap;
        }

    };

    requestQueue.add(request);


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                //configureButton();
                return;
    }
}

private void configureButton() {

       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    textView.setText("jangcy2");
}
```

}

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I'm struggling with the same error message. "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference"  I'm curious what api level you're targetting, I recently moved up to 23 from 18 and runtime permissions feel like they may be the cause here.

Comment: Hi Jeff, unfortunately, I abandoned this project some time ago, but in few days I will have to come back to it. I think my target could be 23 though, and minimum 8.